# TYPO3 ver.: 6.2 Error at Installation

Tags: php, installation, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

When I'm trying to install TYPO3 ver.: 6.2 it shows me the following error:

> Warning: Declaration of TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\FailsafePackageManager::registerPackagesFromConfiguration() should be compatible with TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\PackageManager::registerPackagesFromConfiguration($registerOnlyNewPackages = false) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Template\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Package\FailsafePackageManager.php on line 24

Afterwards i couldn´t connect anymore to the repository to download an extension. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

6.2 is not compatible to PHP7, therefore stay with PHP5.6 or upgrade to TYPO3 7 or 8!

Answer (score 1):

This also happend to me when using Typo3 6.2LTS with php7. I fixed it in file typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Package\FailsafePackageManager.php line 66:

before

```
protected function registerPackagesFromConfiguration() {
```

after:

```
protected function registerPackagesFromConfiguration($registerOnlyNewPackages = false) {
```

Comment: I made these changes at the file and the error doesnt appear anymore, but the problem with the updating of the extension manager isnt solved

Comment: @Perhp I'm no Typo3 expert so I can't help you with that. You could try the typo3 forum or just install the extension manually. Fyi Typo3 version 6.2 should be used with PHP 5.3.7 - 5.6.x see here: https://typo3.org/download/#c3140